# Update on joined data.table subset throws recycled warning

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables (call them dt1 and dt2), dt1 contains an id variable that can be duplicated across records.  dt2 contains all possible unique values of the id from dt1 as well as a unique id assigned to that well call id2. dt1 contains only a subset of all possible id values where dt2 contains the whole set.

I want to update dt1 with the matched value of id2 from dt2. Which led me to following code that works some of the time, and other times it gives me a warning that values are being recycled when assigning id_new.

```
dt1[ dt2, id_new := id2, nomatch = 0 ]
```

Below is a reproducible set of codes that shows when it works and when it doesn't.

```
set.seed(1)
# dt_big can contain duplicate id values 
dt_big <- data.table(id    = letters[c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5)],
                 value = sample(8),
                 key   = "id")

# dt_small contains unique big_id values as well as it's own unique
dt_small <- data.table(id = 1:5,
                    big_id    = letters[1:5],
                       key   = "big_id")

# This works fine
dt_big[dt_small, id_new := i.id,nomatch=0]
dt_big
```

Now we subset dt_big so it's smaller than dt_small and dt_big still includes duplicate ids

```
dt_big <- data.table(id    = letters[c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5)],
                     value = sample(8),
                     key   = "id")
dt_big_sub_dups <- dt_big[c(1,1,5)]

# Again this works fine
dt_big_sub_dups[dt_small,id_new := i.id, nomatch=0]
dt_big_sub_dups
```

Now we sub dt_big to be smaller than dt_small but only include unique values

```
dt_big <- data.table(id    = letters[c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5)],
                     value = sample(8),
                     key   = "id")
dt_big_sub_no_dups <- dt_big[c(1,3,6)]

# Gives warning ... Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 5 items of column id_new' ...
dt_big_sub_no_dups[dt_small,id_new := i.id, nomatch=0]
dt_big_sub_no_dups
```

This also gives incorrect results

```
   id value id_new
1:  a     7      1
2:  b     8      2
3:  d     5      1
```

id_new should = 4 when id="d"

Comment: What is your version of `data.table`? It seems I get correct results with version `1.9.5` (the devel one).

Comment: Does it work the way you want after upgrading to the devel version?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am using v1.9.4 and I just tried 1,9,5 which worked perfect.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table` version `1.9.5` (and a `set.seed(42)`):

```
dt_big_sub_no_dups
#    id value id_new
# 1:  a     8      1
# 2:  b     3      2
# 3:  d     7      4
```